# How to wrap an entire JavaScript file in a named function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here's my situation:

I have 4 JS files - `globalCalc.js`, `calc1.js`, `calc2.js`, `calc3.js`. The three calc files represent different calculators. The `globalCalc.js` must be loaded for every one of those to work (it's the JS that puts the calculators into the DOM). This is all third party code and should not be modified.

My requirements are to put all those calculators, as well as the `globalCalc.js` in one huge js file. However, there are namespace conflicts. For example, `calc1.js` will not load at all if `calc2.js` is loaded after it. I've tried to fiddle with each calc's `initialize` function and override, but it just won't budge - the `globalCalc.js` is designed in such a manner that it would require heavy modification to that file itself in order for everything to load properly.

So, my idea is to somehow wrap every one of these calculators in a named function, and then call it from my HTML. I know this seems silly because I could technically simply send an async GET request and load the calculators when needed, but the requirements are that I put them in a single file.

Is something like this doable:

```
function loadCalc1() { 
    / ** the entire calc1 code, i.e. the contents of the calc1.js file **/
};

function loadCalc2() { 
    / ** same as above, except for calc2.js **/
};
```

And then in my HTML have something like:

`<script>loadCalc1();</script>`

Would this be the way to do it? Or is there a better way to solve this problem? (other than sending separate GET requests)

**EDIT**: I solved my problem doing what I stated. I simply merged the existing js files, previously wrapping them with the functions as mentioned above. In my script tag, I simply execute that function and that's it.

Comment: Putting 4 files into 1 file, is kinda icky.  Why not just create a helper JS file that loads them all, OR just include them in the order needed via script tags.  It sounds like you are trying to do vague object Oriented like Programming.  Creating a function which executes a bunch of sub code.

Comment: This is typically what frameworks like http://requirejs.org/ are used for

Comment: You write that you can't alter the 3rd party files. But can you copy them together in one file and put some JS around?

Comment: @Fallenreaper that is exactly the problem. If I put 3 separate script tags for 3 calculators in whatever order, only the last calculator is displayed on the screen. 

For the other two comments, I know it sounds silly - but those are just the requirements I have. I'd love to have the liberty to do what I want.

Comment: You could still wrap them all with function names, and keep them in different files.  That way the functions defined would be executed and the files would still be separate.

Comment: @Fallenreaper it is a requirement that I keep all of them in one file. Could you tell me how I can wrap them all with function names? Is it the same as I asked in my question?

Comment: The potential problem with wrapping the functions in function wrappers is that they may make the assumption that they can willy-nilly create global symbols implicitly. If the code is wrapped in a function, that will no longer work.

Answer (score 4):

If you can spend some hours, learn to use [requirejs.org](http://requirejs.org/), as blgt mentioned. It is one of the best possible investments in writing proper structured code with Javascript.

Requirejs will solve namespace problems, it will save time to load modules and it offers a lot more optimization.

If you don't have the time, look at these outstanding explanation of Javascript module patterns:

http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html

They are not so difficult, and they will help you to keep your calculators separated yet accessible.

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately for me and everyone else, we cannot include requirejs. However, I will definitely look at the other link you posted.

Comment: Glad to help. Often we don't have much freedom, but anyway the important work is done by proper wrapping code in module structures like `var myModule = (function() { ... })();` and others. Doing so, we organize the essential relationships and interfaces.

Comment: I just did that - or rather, something similar. I'll probably now end up using the `myModule` way anyway.